# unbound method MyFunction() must be called with Tools instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python, class

When I'm trying to call my function from my class this error raised.
This is my class:

```
class Tools:
    def PrintException(self):
        # Do something
        return 'ok'
```

View.py:

```
from tools import Tools

def err(request):
    a = 10
    b = 0
    msg = ""
    try:
        print a / b
    except Exception,ex:
        c = Tools
    return HttpResponse(Tools.PrintException())
```

I've tried to search and have found many articles about this error but I think none of them are my problem!
[unbound method must be called with instance as first argument (got nothing instead)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442466/unbound-method-must-be-called-with-instance-as-first-argument-got-nothing-inste)
[unbound method f() must be called with fibo_ instance as first argument (got classobj instance instead)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473184/unbound-method-f-must-be-called-with-fibo-instance-as-first-argument-got-cla)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you assign to `c` is a class, not an instance of a class. You should do:

```
c = Tools()
```

Further, you should call the method on the instance:

```
def err(request):
    a = 10
    b = 0
    msg = ""
    try:
        print a / b
    except Exception,ex:
        c = Tools()
        return HttpResponse(c.PrintException())
```

Note, that I've changed the indentation so the `return` statement is executed only on exception. This is the only way I can think of to make some sense out of it - it is unclear what are you trying to achieve exactly with your `Tools` class. This name is too generic - it doesn't tell anything about the purpose of this class.

Answer (score 2):

To use your method without an instance of a class you can attach a class method decorator like so:

```
class Tool:
    @classmethod
    def PrintException(cls):
        return 'ok'
```

can be used:

```
>>> Tool.PrintException()
'ok'
>>>
```